# I am creating a small program in java which asks for 5 integers to inputted by the user and put into an array

Tags: java, arrays, validation

This is the code that I have attempted, I can get the 5 integers into the array but my problem is validating that input and giving an error message when it is not. If I put in the 5 integers and they are in the required range it works and when I input a number that is not in the required the range I get an error message which is what I want but if I enter a symbol or letter my program crashes.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuestionNr1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Keyboard Initialization
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Declare an array to hold 5 integers values
        int list[] = new int[5];
        int i = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        System.out.println("Please enter 5 numbers within the range 1 - 20, with 1 being the lowest and 20 being the highest.");
        while (i < 5) {
            //Fill the array with integers from the keyboard (range: 0 to 20).
            int value = scanner.nextInt();
            if (value >= 0 && value <= 20) {
                list[i] = value;
                i++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input, please enter a number with the required range of 1 - 20.");
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
            int value = list[j];
        }

        double average = 0;
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < list.length; i1++) {
            sum = sum + list[i1];
        }
        System.out.print("The sum total of your five entered numbers = " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: "my programme crashes". What is the error message?

Comment: sorry my loops never ends and I have to close eclipse down to get it to stop

Answer (score 2):

```
//Fill the array with integers from the keyboard (range: 0 to 20).
int value = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
if (scanner.hasNextInt()) int value = scanner.nextInt();
else System.out.println("Please make sure the value you entered is an integer.");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check that the user inserts an int before assuming so (`scanner.nextInt();`).

Comment: That's not how you check if the next entered is an int.

Comment: Yes, but he calls scanner.nextInt() and therefore assumes, that the user inserts an int.

Comment: So that's still not how you check. Or do I not understand?

Comment: Of course not, but that's not what I wroter either.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `scanner.nextInt();` so it is expected that the text entered will be `int` and if you enter other then `int` it will throw `exception`

Answer (score 0):

I would use scanner.nextLine() and then try to convert String into int with NumberFormatException check:

```
int value;
String input = scanner.nextLine();
try {
    value = Integer.valueOf(input);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    System.out.println("Number format exception");
    continue;
}
if (value >= 0 && value <= 20)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing Q1 for C2 paper in DCU than its the Sum total you display at the end not the average. I was going to do add another While loop after the scanner.nextint() to test the input is  a valid integer. The 3 validations would be is number an integer and is it in range and the number of integers to be entered to the array is 5. I am thinking very similar to you, its adding the extra check and where is goes in the sequence.

Comment: thank you, I am trying to do that q, think I have cracked it and I am moving on to q2